# Why is there an Import error in main source file while running pytest only?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, python-import

Why is there an import error when running pytest? I can normally access the main files in pylib_example/ just fine.

```
preetam@preddy-Desktop:~/Desktop/pylib_example$ tree
.
├── pylib_example
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   │   └── pyfile2.cpython-38.pyc
│   ├── pyfile1.py
│   └── pyfile2.py
├── setup.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
    │   └── test_pyfile2.cpython-38-pytest-6.2.5.pyc
    └── test_pyfile2.py

4 directories, 10 files
```

pyfile1.py:

```
import configparser

def file1_func1():
    return "File1 Func1"

def file1_func2():
    return "File2 func2"
```

pyfile2.py:

```
import pyfile1

def file2_func1():
    print("{}".format(pyfile1.file1_func1()))
    return pyfile1.file1_func1()
```

test_pyfile2.py:

```
from pylib_example import pyfile2
import pytest

def test_file2_func1():
    print("**********")
    assert pyfile2.file2_func1() == "File1 Func1"
```

```
preetam@preddy-Desktop:~/Desktop/pylib_example$ pytest
=============================================================================================== test session starts ===============================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.10, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /home/preetam/Desktop/pylib_example
plugins: cov-2.12.1
collected 0 items / 1 error                                                                                                                                                                                       

===================================================================================================== ERRORS ======================================================================================================
_____________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_pyfile2.py ______________________________________________________________________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/home/preetam/Desktop/pylib_example/tests/test_pyfile2.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests/test_pyfile2.py:1: in <module>
    from pylib_example import pyfile2
pylib_example/pyfile2.py:1: in <module>
    import pyfile1
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyfile1'
============================================================================================= short test summary info =============================================================================================
ERROR tests/test_pyfile2.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
================================================================================================ 1 error in 0.05s =================================================================================================
```

Comment: try: `PYTHONPATH=. pytest`

Comment: Same result as before

Comment: ``from . import pyfile1`` instead of ``import pyfile1``. The latter is a top-level name.

Answer (score 0):

when we run any script, the folder containing the script becomes the path and all the imports should be corresponding to that path only.

In order to run any script from the current directory, we need to run

```py
python -m script.py
```

## Solution: 1

Here in this case. pytest runs from the root dir, so we can write imports like this

### tests/test_pyfile2.py

```py
from pylib_example import pyfile2
import pytest

def test_file2_func1():
    print("**********")
    assert pyfile2.file2_func1() == "File2 func2"
```

### pylib_example/pyfile2.py

```py
from pylib_example import pyfile1

def file2_func1():
    print("{}".format(pyfile1.file1_func1()))
    return pyfile1.file1_func1()
```

### pylib_example/pyfile1.py

```py
import configparser

def file1_func1():
    return "File1 Func1"

def file1_func1():
    return "File2 func2"
```

## Solution: 2

You can also append the path, to simplify the import, but this is not a good solution.

### tests/test_pyfile2.py

```py
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath("relative path to your pylib_example"))

import pyfile2
import pytest

def test_file2_func1():
    print("**********")
    assert pyfile2.file2_func1() == "File2 func2"
```

#### Note: Keep the remaining file same as it is in your question

Comment: Solution has issues when importing locally in a real usecase. It might work when installed in the python library path though.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pylib_example'

Comment: Solution 2 did not work at all.

Comment: 1. Check the edit, to put the correct path
2. what is your python path? Aren't you using any virtual env?

Note: I actually tested them, by running them on my local machine, it is working for me

If possible put out further details.

Comment: ``python -m script.py`` roughly means running the file ``script/py.py``. I don't think that's what you intended to suggest.

Comment: I was suggesting this in a general term, you are right, this has nothing to do with the solution